# Unable to view navigation UI layout editor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using Android Studio 3.2.1 and I have enabled the navigation UI editor by enabling the preference 'Experimental'--> 'Enable Navigation Editor'

When I try to add a navigation resource file, I'm able to add it to the project but when I tap on the 'Design' tab I get this message

```
This operation requires library 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:.'
```

[image: Add dependency error message]

If I tap OK to add the dependency, I see this error message.

```
'Failed to Add Dependency'
'Failed to add navigation library dependency'
```

[image: Failed to add dependency error message]

I have this dependency in my gradle file

```
// Navigation Components

implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:$rootProject.navigationVersion"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:$rootProject.navigationVersion"

//implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$rootProject.navigationVersion"
//implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$rootProject.navigationVersion"
```

My project is fully based in Kotlin and I get the same error regardless of whether I use the ktx version.

My dependency versions in the main gradle file are

```
kotlinVersion = '1.3.11'
gradleVersion = '3.2.1'
navigationVersion = '1.0.0-alpha08'
```

Comment: I also tried this with a brand new empty project file and I'm seeing the same problem.

Comment: Try to use navigationVersion = '1.0.0-alpha09'